# Deserializing interfaces with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, enums, interface, spring-data-mongodb

i've currently a problem with the serialize/deserialize in MongoDB of an object that contains an attribute defined by a marker interface. The implementations are Enum.

My versions are Spring 4.3.7 and Spring-data-mongodb 1.10.1.

My code sounds like:

```
public interface EventType {
    String getName(); 
}

public interface DomainEvent extends Serializable {

    UUID getId();    
    LocalDateTime getOccurredOn();    
    EventType getEventType();    
    String getEventName();    
}

public abstract class AbstractDomainEvent implements DomainEvent {

    private UUID id;
    private LocalDateTime occurredOn;
    private EventType eventType;

    protected AbstractDomainEvent(EventType eventType) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.occurredOn = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }
}

public class MyEventOne extends AbstractDomainEvent {

    private Object myConcreteData;

    public MyEventOne(Object data) {

        super(MyEventType.EVENT_ONE);
        this.myConcreteData = data;
    }    
}

public enum MyEventType implements EventType {

    EVENT_ONE,
    EVENT_N;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }    
}
```

Ok, well.

My problem is when I try to deserialize an event persisted in mongoDB.

When I persist MyEventOne, Spring data mongo persist the object as:

```
{
        "_class" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.MyEventOne",
        "_id" : LUUID("d74478e7-258c-52c4-4fc5-aba20a30d4b6"),
        "occurredOn" : ISODate("2018-02-21T14:39:53.549Z"),
        "eventType" : "EVENT_ONE"
        }
    }
```

Note the eventType is a String.

When I try to read this document, I have this exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [xxx.xxx.xxx.EventType]
```

Any idea? there a some solution like a insert metadata information about the concrete Enum instance, like a "_class" field?

I try insert @JsonTypeInfo annotation in EventType attribute at AbstractDomainEvent but it doesnt works.

Thank you!!!

Comment: In MongodB document you have EVENT_PROCESSED, but in your enum that is not defined. You only have EVENT_ONE and EVENT_N. how can it map?

Comment: Sorry @pvpkiran, its a write error, i solved.

Comment: Enums are stored as string. Automatic conversion should work. If it isn't working, try adding a mongoconverter

Comment: thanks @pvpkiran, yes, automatic conversion should work normally when the model object has a instance of Enum, but in this case has a instance of a marker interface that is implements by an Enum. Spring-data-mongo dont know which interface implementation create. It's common problem with others serializers but i dont know why in this case doesnt works, e.g., @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "eventTypeClass")

Comment: you need to write a converter for this. there is no other option